# Como identifico qual fragment atual quando usar o botão volta do android?

Tags: java, android

Bom dia galera, tudo bem? 
Estou com o seguinte problema:

Entro no fragment inicial do app e nessa tela tenho uma PagerView, quando troco de fragment e volto usando o **BOTÃO BACK** para o fragment inicial essa imagem some. Então eu coloquei dentro do **onBackPressed** o código que carrega a imagem e deu certo, mas ela só pode carregar quando for o fragment inicial, por isso eu tenho que saber para qual fragment o back trouxe, preciso do id para comprar ou algo para comparar:

Exemplo sem verificar o fragment no OnBackPressed:
Fragment A  foi para Fragment B
Fragment B voltou para Fragment A
DEU BOM!!

agora se eu faço isso:
Fragment A  foi para Fragment B
Fragment B foi para o Fragment C
quando tentar voltar para o B, vai dar pau porque nele não tem o PagerView que o metodo chama.

Então gostaria de um jeito de verificar para qual fragment o BackPress irá levar para eu verificar se é igual o meu (R.id.nav_prg)

Comment: Eu tenho uma variável global e no evento onResume de cada fragmento seto essa variável. Desse modo consigo saber em que fragmento estava quando o botão voltar foi pressionado.

Comment: então, mas o onResume executa depois do onBackPressed do MainActivity, logo não teria como eu saber se era o Fragment A. Dentro do main eu instacio uma classe Fragment A e uso um metodo, só que o metodo só irá funciona se o onBack estiver indo para o Fragmento A, caso contrario da pau!

Comment: Eu já tentei chamar o meu metodo de criar o PagerView no onResume do Fragment A, mas não funcionou... se tivesse dado certo eu nem iria precisar desse metodo no MainActivity

Comment: Hmmm. Em sua lógica me parece que colocar no evento onPause qual fragmento esta sendo encerrado funcionária.

Comment: Compreendi pouco o que você quer fazer. Me parece um pouco confuso.

Comment: o Problema é o seguinte, estou criando uma rádio e o topo dela é um PagerView com as estações, quando faz Swipe muda a estação. Quando iniciar a aplicação carrega o topo(PagerView) no Fragment A, quando eu troco para o Fragment B e volto para o Fragment A, o topo não carrega novamente, mesmo eu colocando nos metodos onPause, onResume e OnStart o metodo que inicia o topo. Agora quando eu uso para chamar o metodo lá no MainActivity, onde fica o onBackPressed, ai funciona.

Comment: Mas ai sempre vai chamar o Metodo de carregar o topo, mas esse topo só existe no Fragment A, caso eu esteja no Fragment C e o onBackPressed volte para o Fragmento B vai dar PAU, porque só no Fragment A existe!

Comment: Por isso preciso saber o id do Fragement que o onBackPressed está voltando para eu comparar se é igual ao do Fragment A!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando isto dentro do meu onBackPressed:

```
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int valueBackStack = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (valueBackStack>1) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if(String.valueOf(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(valueBackStack-2).getName()).equals("radioNoAr")){
               fragmentRadioLive.mountTop();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }else if(valueBackStack==1){
        finish();
    }
```

depois de definir um nome para cada Fragment eu consigo pegar esse nome usando isso *fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(**posição no back**).getName()* ai foi só comprar com o nome e já era!