# Como saber qual Fragment está sendo exibida

Tags: android, android-fragment

Meu app possui uma Activity que controla a inclusão dos Fragments.

Segue:

```
public static void adicionarFragment(Activity activity, Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragMgr = activity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        fragTrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fragTrans.commit();
    }
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível descobrir qual Fragment está sendo exibida   ?

Existe alguma forma de desobrir utitlizando o `FragmentManager`?

Ps: Tentei [desta forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184537/25969), mas ele não me retorna a instancia da Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No momento do replace, vc deve setar uma TAG pro seu Fragment, exemplo:

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id. content, fragment, "TAG_DO_FRAGMENT");
```

Depois para checar qual o Fragment está sendo exibido, faça dessa forma:

```
 NomeDoFragment nomeFragment = (NomeDoFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_DO_FRAGMENT");
 if (nomeFragment != null && nomeFragment.isVisible()) {

   // se entrar aqui ele está visível

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o método [getFragments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragments()) do [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) para obter uma lista de todos os fragments adicionados a ele.

```
List<Fragment> fragments = fragMgr.getFragments();
```

Não é completamente claro no seu código mas, já que usa `replace()`, parece-me que no seu caso apenas haverá um Fragment adicionado.
Assim, a lista retornada terá apenas um item e esse é o que procura.

```
Fragment visibleFragment = fragments.get(0);
```

Para distinguir um Fragment de outro, ao fazer o *replace*, use uma String/Tag:

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, "Tag1");
```

Depois, poderá fazer qualquer coisa assim:

```
Fragment visibleFragment = fragments.get(0);
switch (visibleFragment.getTag()){
    case "Tag1":
        ...
        break;
    case "Tag2":
        ...
        break;
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!